# Is this right to say "It has been 20 years since they have seen each other."

Tags: grammar, tense, expressions

I saw this sentence below on the internet.
It has been 20 years since they have seen each other.
Is this right expression?
Should I collect like "It has been 20 years since they saw each other."

Comment: You would more clearly the first if you mean that they've been apart for a long time, and the second if you're talking the time since a specific meeting in the past.  But speakers will use either in both cases and understand each other from context.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the context.

If two children were separated at birth and their parents witnessed their meeting again for the first time in 20 years, one parent might say to the other:

> It has been 20 years since they have seen each other.

That's to say that the meeting is continuing or just finished.

But if the parents were talking about a meeting that took place earlier, they would say;

> It's been 20 years since they saw each other

because the meeting was already in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. We can use either.

We can use the simple past (***they saw* each other**) or present perfect (***they have seen* each other**) after since.

We can also say, '**It is** 20 years since they saw each other'. ('It has been 20 years…' is more common in American English than 'It is 20 years...')

-'How long is it since they saw each other?'

-'It is 20 years since they saw each other.'

Answer (score 0):

Both versions of the sentence are grammatically correct, but they have slightly different meanings:

1. "It has been 20 years since they have seen each other."
   This sentence uses the present perfect tense ("have seen") to indicate that the action of seeing each other happened at some point in the past, and the 20-year period is still ongoing. It implies that they haven't seen each other in the 20 years leading up to the present moment.
2. "It has been 20 years since they saw each other."
   This sentence uses the simple past tense ("saw") to indicate that the action of seeing each other occurred at a specific point in the past, and the 20-year period is also completed. It implies that they haven't seen each other in the 20 years that have passed since that specific point in the past.

So, both versions are grammatically correct, but the choice between them depends on the specific context and the exact meaning you want to convey. If you want to emphasize that the 20-year period is still ongoing, the first version with the present perfect tense is more appropriate. If you want to emphasize that the 20-year period is completed, the second version with the simple past tense is more suitable.